# addEventListener or calling functions from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a question was told to "not to mix up languages HTML and JavaScript together".

Mainly I heard this statement in JS tutorials using addEventListener instead of function called directly from html (for example onfocusout or onclick). In my opinion - modest newbie - calling functions from HTML (like onclick etc.) is more comfortable.

But, w3schools says that “addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.”, but I know that IE8 is practically extinct and unused by anyone.

Which is "good practics" and what will be better for my code?

Using addEventListener or calling functions from HTML?
Greetings and thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is probably to do something like that from a script file or a script tag, otherwise you'll need to go hunting through your markup to figure out where these things are triggered by

If you have a site and know that ALL of the javascript parts that need to be maintained for a functionality are in one specific part of a file, or better yet, in one single file, it makes maintenance easier

The general idea is that even if it may be slightly less convenient when writing it at first, it's better in the long term for maintenance

You always want to try and make things easier for the next guy to work on it, because chances are, it's going to be you